# Listing in WCF Entity

Tags: c#, linq, wcf

I have a problem with LINQ query (see comment) there is a First method and it only shows me the first element.

When I write in the console "Sales Representative" it shows me only the first element of it as in

[image: this picture]

I would like to get all of data about Sales Representative. How can I do it?

```
public PracownikDane GetPracownik(string imie)
{
    PracownikDane pracownikDane = null;

  using (NORTHWNDEntities database = new NORTHWNDEntities())
    {
        //Employee matchingProduct = database.Employees.First(p => p.Title == imie);

            var query = from pros in database.Employees

                        where pros.Title == imie
                        select pros;

        // Here

        Employee pp = query.First();

        pracownikDane = new PracownikDane();
        pracownikDane.Tytul = pp.Title;
        pracownikDane.Imie = pp.FirstName;
        pracownikDane.Nazwisko = pp.LastName;
        pracownikDane.Kraj = pp.Country;
        pracownikDane.Miasto = pp.City;
        pracownikDane.Adres = pp.Address;
        pracownikDane.Telefon = pp.HomePhone;
        pracownikDane.WWW = pp.PhotoPath;

    }
    return pracownikDane;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please copy & paste the code in the body of your question and indicate where is the problem. Otherwise, it's quite difficult to get any help. Thanks :)

Comment: Remove the First() and replace with a loop:

foreach(var pp in Query)
{
//print out all rep info for that 'pp' that you want

}

Comment: Hey guys bill could you explain it more clear i'm newbie so i don't quiet understan i mean i know what's foreach but where to put it on :)

Answer (score 0):

Right  now you are just getting the .First() result from the Query collection:

```
Employee pp = query.First();
```

If you want to list all employees you need to iterate through the entire collection.

Now, if you want to return all the employee's you should then store each new "pracownikDane" you create in some sort of IEnumerable

```
public IEnumerable<PracownikDane> GetPracownik(string imie) { 

  using (NORTHWNDEntities database = new NORTHWNDEntities())
    {
      var query = from pros in database.Employees
                        where pros.Title == imie
                        select pros;

      var EmployeeList = new IEnumerable<PracownikDane>();
      foreach(var pp in query)
      {
        EmployeeList.Add(new PracownikDane()
        {
         Tytul = pp.Title,
         Imie = pp.FirstName,
         Nazwisko = pp.LastName,
         Kraj = pp.Country,
         Miasto = pp.City,
         Adres = pp.Address,
         Telefon = pp.HomePhone,
         WWW = pp.PhotoPath
        });        
      }
    return EmployeeList;
}
```

Then, with this returned List you can then do what ever you wanted with them.

Comment: bill it's not working in the second post are errors can you check why?

Comment: Any other ideas guys? It's really important for me :/ If you have any kind of solution pleas write it down.